# how to install downloaded Intel system images for android emulator in eclipse

Tags: android-emulator

i have installed eclipse and android sdk. Also eclipse required plug in for sdk. I want to install system image for emulator without using sdk manager as i have already downloaded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Android SDK Manager and it will show you the list of available System Images. Just choose the one you need and click on download. 
[image]